# R - aggregate(), using na.action to not drop data

Tags: r, sum, aggregate, na

I feel like I have done this before and have no idea why I am not figuring it out all of the sudden. I am simply trying to aggregate data using the aggregate() function, without dropping any rows where the grouping terms are NA. I also do not want to have to worry about converting NAs to anything like character strings... Given the following:

```
 FOO_BAR <- data.frame(Foo=c(rep("omg", 6), rep(NA, 6), rep("omg", 6), rep(NA, 6)), 
                       Bar=c(rep("This", 6), rep("is", 6), rep("so", 6), rep("annoying", 6)), 
                       Doh=rnorm(24))
```

I would like to use the following:

```
aggregate(data=FOO_BAR, Doh ~ ., FUN=sum, na.action=na.pass, na.rm=FALSE)
```

To yield something like this:

| Foo | Bar | Doh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| omg | This | ### |
| NA | is | ### |
| omg | so | ### |
| NA | annoying | ### |

I have tried na.action=na.pass, and na.action=NULL. I have tried playing around with the class of the variable "Foo". I would like to solve it using aggregate(), and not another method such as summarize(). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not with `aggregate`, but with the default behavior of `factor`, which excludes `NA`:

```
FOO_BAR$Foo <- factor(FOO_BAR$Foo, exclude = NULL)
aggregate(data=FOO_BAR, Doh ~ ., FUN=sum)

# OR

FOO_BAR$Foo <- addNA(FOO_BAR$Foo)
aggregate(data=FOO_BAR, Doh ~ ., FUN=sum)
```

`aggregate` coerces your by groups to factors. `?factor` shows the default is `exclude = NA`. If `FOO_BAR$Bar` also had `NA` you would need to do the same thing to include it.

**Output**

You can tell that `Bar` has been converted to a factor. By default, factors are ordered alphabetically, which is why `annoying` comes first and `This` last, so unfortunately `Bar` does not read as you intended :)

```
   Foo      Bar       Doh
1 <NA> annoying -1.520229
2 <NA>       is -1.690467
3  omg       so  2.588006
4  omg     This -4.424476
```

Of course we can fix this behavior -- we would not want your message to get lost. Rather than manually set the `level` argument of `factor` we can use `forcast::fct_inorder`:

```
FOO_BAR$Bar <- forcats::fct_inorder(FOO_BAR$Bar)
aggregate(data=FOO_BAR, Doh ~ ., FUN=sum)
   Foo      Bar       Doh
1  omg     This -4.424476
2 <NA>       is -1.690467
3  omg       so  2.588006
4 <NA> annoying -1.520229
```

---

Alternatively you can simply do:

```
library(dplyr)

FOO_BAR |> 
  summarize(Doh = sum(Doh), 
            .by = c(Foo, Bar))
```

Comment: Like the `factor` method with `exculde=NULL`, +1!

Comment: And as is often the case, this is explicitly documented with example code in the `?aggregate` help file, under the sub-section: `"# and if you want to treat NAs as a group"`

Comment: Thank you for the helpful post - I understand that I can reclass as factor and set exclude=NA prior to passing it through aggregate(). However, because aggregate() coerces the by groups to factors, I thought I remembered an argument within aggregate(), such that you do not have to convert all by groups to factors with exclude=NA beforehand. But now I'm starting to think I imagined it. I guess I was looking for one line of code not using pipes, that accomplishes this, without pre-formatting input data. I am also aware of summarize(), but was specifically trying to use aggregate().

Answer (score 2):

You can try `data.table` like below

```
> library(data.table)

> setDT(FOO_BAR)[, .(Doh = sum(Doh)), .(Foo, Bar)]
    Foo      Bar       Doh
1:  omg     This  2.101502
2: <NA>       is  4.557829
3:  omg       so -1.996853
4: <NA> annoying -1.988226
```